# What is the difference between fitdistr and fitdist for t-distribution?

Tags: r

More specifically, I have a set of data `x` e.g

```
x <- scan(textConnection(
"10.210126 10.277015 10.402625 10.208137  9.831884  9.672501  
9.815476  9.980124  9.710509  9.148997  9.406072
9.991224 10.324005 10.402747 10.449439 10.051304  9.886748  9.771041
9.761175 10.049102  9.457981  9.114380 9.461333  9.804220 10.395986
10.192419 10.202962  9.984330  9.765604  9.473166  9.966462 10.120895 
9.631744"))
```

If I use

```
fitdist(x,"t")
```

I get the following results:

```
        m             s            df     
  10.63855874    0.50766169   37.08954639 
 ( 0.02217171) ( 0.01736012) (23.12225558)
```

Compared to

```
fitdist(x,"t",start=list(length(x)-1,mean(x)),lower=c(0))
```

(starting parameters were found in an answer on this site) which results in:

```
     estimate Std. Error
1 103129.28018         NA
2     10.63869         NA
```

Why is there a difference? Am I perhaps using the wrong starting points for fitdist()?

Comment: please specify what packages `fitdistr` and `fitdist` come from (`MASS`, ??).  Can you add a link to the SO question you got the starting parameters from?

Comment: Estimating `df` is known to be very difficult.

Comment: fitdistr is from MASS and fitdist is from fitdistrplus. I can't find the link anymore, but the context was that the questioner had issues using 'fitdist' as start parameters weren't specified. The only answer was to put in `start=list(length(x)-1,mean(x)`. If you're referring to the `lower=c(0)` I figured since my data was >0 it would be a good bound to use.

Comment: I can't replicate this with `fitdistrplus::fitdist` (I get "Unknown starting values" if I leave out the starting values and "mle failed to estimate the parameters" if I specify them as above); if I use `MASS::fitdistr` I get "optimization failed" without starting values and `MASS::fitdistr(x,"t",start=list(df=length(x)-1,m=mean(x),s=sd(x)),lower=c(0))` gives a large value of df (but not identical to your example). Can you edit your question to give (1) an exactly reproducible example (2) results of `sessionInfo`, or at least the versions of the packages you're using?